# Why aren't relationships created when posting cypher using curl?

Tags: curl, neo4j, cypher

I execute the below code using curl (everything is on one line when I truly run it. I break it down here so that it's easier to read). Nodes are created successfully but the relationships are not. It doesn't recognize the relationships between the nodes.

```
curl --user neo4j:mypassword -i -H accept:application/json -H 
content-type:application/json -XPOST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit -d 
'{"statements":[
{"statement":"CREATE (keanu:Actor { name : '\''Keanu Reeves'\''}) return id(keanu)"},
{"statement":"CREATE (chad:Director { name : '\''Chad Stahelski'\''}) return id(chad)"},
{"statement":"CREATE (david:Director { name : '\''David Leitch'\''}) return id(david)"},
{"statement":"CREATE (william:Actor { name : '\''William Dafoe'\''}) return id(william)"},
{"statement":"CREATE (michael:Actor { name : '\''Michael Nyquist'\''}) return id(michael)"},
{"statement":"CREATE (movienew:Movie { title : '\''John Wick'\''}) return id(movienew)"},
{"statement":"CREATE (keanu)-[:ACTS_IN ]->(movienew)"},
{"statement":"CREATE (chad)-[:Directed_IN ]->(movienew)"},
{"statement":"CREATE (david)-[:Directed_IN ]->(movienew)"},
{"statement":"CREATE (william)-[:ACTS_IN ]->(movienew)"},
{"statement":"CREATE (michael)-[:ACTS_IN ]->(movienew)"}
]}'
```

[image]

It doesn't recognize the relationships are between which nodes.

[image]

How should I fix it?

---

**Update:** I have now changed my code into this

```
curl --user neo4j:mypassword -i -H accept:application/json -H content-type:application/json -XPOST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit -d '{"statements":[{"statement":"CREATE (matrix1:Movie { title : '\''The Matrix'\'', year : '\''1999-03-31'\'' }) return id(matrix1)","CREATE (matrix2:Movie { title : '\''The Matrix Reloaded'\'', year : '\''2003-05-07'\'' }) return id(matrix2)","CREATE (matrix3:Movie { title : '\''The Matrix Revolutions'\'', year : '\''2003-10-27'\'' }) return id(matrix3)","CREATE (keanu:Actor { name : '\''Keanu Reeves'\''}) return id(keanu)","CREATE (laurence:Actor { name : '\''Laurence Fishburne'\''})","CREATE (carrieanne:Actor { name : '\''Carrie-Anne Moss'\''})","CREATE (keanu)-[:ACTS_IN { role : '\''Neo'\'' }]->(matrix1)","CREATE (keanu)-[:ACTS_IN { role : '\''Neo'\'' }]->(matrix2)","CREATE (keanu)-[:ACTS_IN { role : '\''Neo'\'' }]->(matrix3)","CREATE (laurence)-[:ACTS_IN { role : '\''Morpheus'\'' }]->(matrix1)","CREATE (laurence)-[:ACTS_IN { role : '\''Morpheus'\'' }]->(matrix2)","CREATE (laurence)-[:ACTS_IN { role : '\''Morpheus'\'' }]->(matrix3)","CREATE (carrieanne)-[:ACTS_IN { role : '\''Trinity'\'' }]->(matrix1)","CREATE (carrieanne)-[:ACTS_IN { role : '\''Trinity'\'' }]->(matrix2)","CREATE (carrieanne)-[:ACTS_IN { role : '\''Trinity'\'' }]->(matrix3)"}]}'
```

but then I got error 'unable to deserialize request: Unexpected character(','(code 44))'

---

**Update:** Based on the accepted answer, I copied the exact format and applied it to another program but this time i received the error below:

> {"results":[],"errors":    [{"code":"Neo.ClientError.Request.InvalidFormat","message":"Unable to deserialize request: Unexpected character ('.' (code 46)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: HttpInputOverHTTP@442ac29b; line: 1, column: 3]"}]}

my code is:

```
curl --user neo4j:mypassword -i -H accept:application/json \
-H content-type:application/json \
-XPOST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit \
-d @- << EOF
{
    "statements":
    [
      {
       "statement":
        "CREATE (matrix1:Movie { title : 'The Matrix', year : '1999-03-31'})
         CREATE (matrix2:Movie { title : 'The Matrix Reloaded', year : '2003-05-07'})
         CREATE (matrix3:Movie { title : 'The Matrix Revolutions', year : '2003-10-27'})
         CREATE (keanu:Actor { name : 'Keanu Reeves'})
         CREATE (laurence:Actor { name : 'Laurence Fishburne'})
         CREATE (carrieanne:Actor { name : 'Carrie-Anne Moss'})
         CREATE (keanu)-[:ACTS_IN { role : 'Neo' }]->(matrix1)
     CREATE (keanu)-[:ACTS_IN { role : 'Neo' }]->(matrix2)
     CREATE (keanu)-[:ACTS_IN { role : 'Neo' }]->(matrix3)
     CREATE (laurence)-[:ACTS_IN { role : 'Morpheus' }]->(matrix1)
     CREATE (laurence)-[:ACTS_IN { role : 'Morpheus' }]->(matrix2)
     CREATE (laurence)-[:ACTS_IN { role : 'Morpheus' }]->(matrix3)
     CREATE (carrieanne)-[:ACTS_IN { role : 'Trinity' }]->(matrix1)
     CREATE (carrieanne)-[:ACTS_IN { role : 'Trinity' }]->(matrix2)
     CREATE (carrieanne)-[:ACTS_IN { role : 'Trinity' }]->(matrix3) 
     RETURN *"
  }
]
}
EOF
```

Can someone please tell me why this is not correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best approach is to remove a bunch of those unnecessary ticks so you can see what you are doing a little better. As @inversefalcon says you lose context when you execute each statement. You want to keep it all in one so the identifiers from each `CREATE` are preserved for when you create the relationships at the end.

You should be able to cut and paste this block as-is.

```
curl --user neo4j:password -i -H accept:application/json \
  -H content-type:application/json \
  -XPOST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit \
  -d @- << END_OF_CYPHER
{
  "statements":
  [
    {
      "statement":
        "CREATE (keanu:Actor { name : 'Keanu Reeves'})
         CREATE (chad:Director { name : 'Chad Stahelski'})
         CREATE (david:Director { name : 'David Leitch'})
         CREATE (william:Actor { name : 'William Dafoe'})
         CREATE (michael:Actor { name : 'Michael Nyquist'})
         CREATE (movienew:Movie { title : 'John Wick'})
         CREATE (keanu)-[:ACTS_IN ]->(movienew)
         CREATE (chad)-[:Directed_IN ]->(movienew)
         CREATE (david)-[:Directed_IN ]->(movienew)
         CREATE (william)-[:ACTS_IN ]->(movienew)
         CREATE (michael)-[:ACTS_IN ]->(movienew)
         RETURN *"
     }
  ]
}
END_OF_CYPHER
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! this is beautiful. What does this EOF stands for?

Comment: it is just a label so that the shell knows when it reads the end of the input.  EOF is just traditional *end of file*.

Comment: I see. I used this exact format for another problem but get an error message (code shows in my above post). Can you please let me know why this is not correct?

Comment: looks good - my guess is control character or something? I cut n' pasted your cypher block as-is changed the password and it worked on my 3.1.1 local community edition.

Answer (score 2):

Separate statements have separate scope for variables. Once you're in the next statement, any previous variables are not available.

This is why in each of your relationship creation statements, the variables you're using are brand new, so a new triple of blank nodes connected by the given relationship are created per relationship creation statement.

To avoid this, you need to run all lines of the creation query in a single statement (and get rid of those returns, at least until the last line).

Comment: I update my post - i tried what you suggested but got an error... Could you please tell me what's wrong?

Comment: For a single statement, do not have separate Strings separated by commas. It's a single string, no returns (at least until the very end), and no commas between clauses.